# Best way to run virtual servers on a ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on a physical box.

For web development testing purposes I would like to set up several virtual servers ( Ubuntu, Windows XP with IE6, Windows XP with IE7, .... )

What is the best way to achive that?

Also: Is there a web interface solution to see which servers are up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by "Virtual servers": it could be two things:

(a) You want to run other instances of ubuntu server (like other physical computers) on top of your existing system. The answer to that would be:

To me the best option would be KVM -  this is a kernel based virtual machine, meaning that it uses the host os's kernel for tasks such as memory allocation etc.... A good place to start would be: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM

OR

(b) if you are talking about Apache virtual servers then you should definitely look into using webmin or virtualmin to manage your server: www.virtualmin.com

Hope that helps,
RayQuang

Answer (score 5):

You can use KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine). The following URL will teach you how to install it on Ubuntu.

http://www.ideyatech.com/2010/05/virtualization-with-ubuntu-1004-lucid-lynx/

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this solution however the network bridge does not work. Similar to a comment there, my server is not reachable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can install VMWare Server on your Ubuntu machine and provided it has enough resources, it should run all your virtual machines. I currently have a 4Gig Xeon quad core ubuntu machine with 3 VM's created - Windows Server, Windows XP and Solaris.